# Update a ComboBox selection based on a DataGridView cell value?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want my combo boxes to change based on the what is selected on my datagridview.

**What I've tried:**

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_SelectionChanged2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.SelectionChanged

With DataGridView2

    If .SelectedRows IsNot Nothing AndAlso .SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .SelectedRows(0)
 
        Form2.ComboBox1.Text = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox2.Text = row.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox3.Text = row.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox4.Text = row.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox5.Text = row.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox6.Text = row.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox7.Text = row.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox8.Text = row.Cells(12).Value.ToString()
        Form2.ComboBox9.Text = row.Cells(13).Value.ToString()
 
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

This code has no effect, but I do feel that I am heading in the right direction.

**This is how I inserted my data into the comboboxes:**

```
      Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM Ingredientes"
            Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("x")
                connection.Open()
                Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
                    Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                    dt.Load(rs)
              
                    ComboBox1.BindingContext = New BindingContext
                    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Articulo"
                    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
' etc
```

Comment: The name of this Sub, `Sub MyDataGridView_SelectionChanged2`, makes me think there is more than one handler for this event. True?

Comment: Put a break point in the code to see if it is running when you expect.

Comment: You can use a BindingSource to syn the combo boxes to the grid.

Comment: Technically the posted code should work. You state that _”This code has no effect…”_ … which begs the question … are you sure the code IS running? The methods signature has some red flag properties that would indicate that there may be some other method getting fired. The “2” at the end of the methods name “implies” that there is possibly another method with the same name and “1” or possibly without a 1 or 2. Point being, the “2” is suspicious and we have no way to know if the event is subscribed to properly. Putting a break point in the method would solve this question.

Comment: In addition, the methods name is suspicious… `MyDataGridView` is the first part of the method, however, the code references a grid named `DataGridView2`? This is certainly legal; however, it can lead to confusion. “Usually” the first part of the event name is the name of the control… in this case `DataGridView2`. Again, there is nothing to stop you from naming the method to anything you want; however, it makes sense to name it properly so it is clear “which” control the event is used for. This helps you in the future and makes it a little clearer for others reading your code.

Comment: @JohnG I just found out that  my code does work. The issue is that I have to reselect the row in order for the comboboxes to update. I also noticed that this only happens when the comboboxes use databound Items.

Comment: @Mary ^. not sure how to tag two people in a comment.

Comment: The combo boxes being data bound is irrelevant. Your issue is coming from somewhere else. If you have to _“reselect the row in order for the comboboxes to update.”_ then this sounds like the event is not firing when you think it is. You need to trace your code. Something is obviously not happening when you think it is and I am confident that a trace of the code will reveal the problem. Have you traced your code?

Comment: @JohnG I did, as soon as a row is added the breakpoint shows the code is executed and the value is correct I swear on my momma John. I even made a new project to simplify everything, and the result is the same.

Comment: I suggest you make a [mre] so we can test it. Currently I am unable to re-produce the issue you describe using your code. _”as soon as a row is added the breakpoint shows the code is executed and the value is correct…”_ … ? … How is “adding” a row related to the posted code?

Answer (score 0):

On DataGridView2 properties go to SelectionMode and select FullRowSelected.

Or add this line code on the Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

```
DataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

If can also remove the ".SelectedRows IsNot Nothing AndAlso" because it will always have a value, even there is nothing selected it will return a Zero not a null.

Comment: Hello Miguel, I already implemented this and my code did work. The issue I have now is I have to reselect the row in order for the comboboxes to update. I noticed this only happens when the comboboxes use data bound items.

Comment: @jumexmango After you fill the datagridview you can use the .ClearSelection to have no rows selected: DataGridView2.ClearSelection, this will force the user to select a row.